# This tag has [zero] meaning

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request

The tag [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) is made up of a variety of languages, and is very unfocused.

It has questions ranging from using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to replace certain text with a zero all the way to the [number of bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_byte_file) in a file.

Some stats about the [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) tag:

- It has [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) followers (see what I did there?)
- It has only 1 tag wiki edit
- It has only been viewed eleven times.
- It has 580+ questions

The [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) tag does not add anything to the questions tagged with it. I propose it be burned until [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) questions are tagged with it (ha, I did it again).

As [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297963/this-tag-has-zero-meaning?noredirect=1#comment311280_297963) by [Tiny Giant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4639281/tiny-giant), there is actually a [language named zero](http://labraj.feri.um.si/en/Programming_language_Zero). I propose that questions having to do with this language are retagged to something like [zero-language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero-language), and the tag [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) is burned. IMO, just cleaning up the [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) tag will have [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) effect the long-term problem of people mis-tagging their questions with [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) (please help I have no friends).

Comment: So I'm assuming by the downvotes some people think this adds meaning to posts. Why is that? We don't have a [one] or [two] tag

Comment: I feel [tag:null] has [tag:zero] use as well. (See what I did there?)

Comment: @Jongware you are ([tag:zero] + 100) percent correct (please help me I'm so alone)

Comment: @Jojodmo would you say that you have [zero](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) friends?

Comment: @mikeTheLiar I laughed so hard when I saw that... I have [tag:zero] breath left

Comment: Three downvotes? I realize I am confused.

Comment: (There should be [tag:zero] downvotes...)

Comment: @KyleStrand They just want to keep the votes on [tag:zero].

Comment: You all, the comments digress.  Let's zero in on the question, please.

Comment: What about the [zero programming language](http://labraj.feri.um.si/en/Programming_language_Zero)?

Comment: @TinyGiant Almost all of the questions tagged with [tag:zero] don't have to do with the language - maybe we should retag the bad questions, and state that [tag:zero] should only be used for questions pertaining to the language

Comment: I would agree with that, but as long as there is something that it could unambiguously relate to, I do not agree with burnination of the tag. A tag [meta-tag:clean-up] would be appropriate.

Comment: As per your edit: 1. We don't have a c-language tag, we have a [tag:c] tag. Sure some people may mis-tag their questions with [tag:c] when they are actually talking about the letter "c", but we don't burninate the tag when someone does so. 2. We don't [optimize for sand, we optimize for pearls](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand). We should [meta-tag:clean-up] the [tag:zero] tag, then update the wiki and excerpt to explicitly state when it should be used.

Comment: @TinyGiant The reasoning behind that naming it zero-language was that there's a *lot* of times that the number zero will come up in programming, but that isn't the same as the letter **c**. You should post an answer expressing your opinion on how to handle this, so the community can vote

Comment: Yes, please burn this useless tag.

Comment: Is the jury still out on this one?

Comment: There are currently (762 + [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero)) questions with this tag.  Apparently, [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) decisions have been made regarding this request so far.  Whoever comes up with the decision regarding this tag will go from [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) to hero.  When will be the [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) hour at which we will have [zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zero) tolerance for this tag?

Answer (score 6):

I just came across this tag today; it now has 973 questions. The tag wiki says this (emphasis mine):

> Zero is a unique number and along with 1 is one of the two binary numbers. Zero plays an important role in Mathematics and Computing. This Tag is for **discussions of zero within various programming languages**.

It seems to me that this explicitly encourages bad questions. Stack Overflow is for specific questions, not for discussions on vague or broad topics!

Let's see how it stacks up against [the criteria for burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination):

1. **Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**
   No. Zero occurs in too many different contexts in programming for the tag "zero" to describe anything about the question content or which expertise might be required to answer the question.
2. **Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
   I do not think that a question *about* the number zero (as opposed to merely *involving* the number zero) could be on-topic for Stack Overflow.
3. **Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
   No. It simply indicates that the question *involves* the number zero in some way. It doesn't indicate that the number zero is relevant to the answer, or that the answer would be different if the question involved a different number.
4. **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
   No. The tag has questions which involve the integer `0`, the character `'0'`, the floating-point value [negative-zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/negative-zero), the timestamp `0000-00-00 00:00:00`; questions where the zero has some numerical meaning (e.g. a file size), questions where it is merely a symbol (e.g. formatting numbers with leading zeroes).

I agree that the tag should be burninated.